# How to make other objects appear every time a certain object in clicked

Tags: javascript, html, brackets

So I have my main page made with the object I want to click on that will make the other objects appear.  I want the main page to remain but with every click I want other objects to appear one by one. I have about 5 layers made of my `index.html` I'm just not exactly sure what code I need to put in each layer so that when I click the main page object the other layers will show up.

Comment: There's really not enough information here to answer your question. Please create a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so people can help

Answer (score 0):

> With every click I want other objects to appear one by one

You can add an event listener which, whenever it detects a click, executes a function which enables each next hidden object to appear.

**Working Example:**

```js
var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var boxNumber = 1;

function revealBox() {
    if (boxNumber < (boxes.length - 2)) {
        boxes[boxNumber].classList.add('revealed');
        boxNumber++;
    }

    if (boxNumber < (boxes.length - 2)) {
        boxes[0].textContent = 'Click me to reveal Box ' + boxNumber;
    }
}

boxes[0].textContent += ' to reveal Box ' + boxNumber;
boxes[0].addEventListener('click', revealBox, false);
```

```css
div {
display: none;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
font-size: 22px;
text-align: center;
background-color: rgb(163, 163, 163);
vertical-align: top;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
display: inline-block;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
cursor: pointer;
}

div.revealed {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>Click Me</div>
<div>Box 1</div>
<div>Box 2</div>
<div>Box 3</div>
<div>Box 4</div>
<div>Box 5</div>
```